# python dela with variable in memory

Tags: python

```
def choice(n,s=[]):
  a=s
  if n==0:
    string=''
    d=[str(a[len(a)-i-1]) for i in range(len(a))]
    string=string.join(d)
    print(string)
    return string
  if (n-1)%2==0:
    a.append(1)
    n=float(n-1)/2
    return choice(n,a)
  if (n-2)%2==0:
    a.append(2)
    n=float(n-2)/2
    return choice(n,a)
choice(10)#this print 122 ,it's right

choice(10)#but when I run it again ,this print 122122
```

I dont know what to do

please help me!!!

Comment: It's because your list `s` is not = `[]` the 2nd time you run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mutable list as a default value is bad practice. Simply changing the top of your function like this will fix it.

```
def choice(n,s=None):
  if s is None:
      s = []
```

Comment: it works !!!! can you tell me why？

Comment: @Kyan http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments